# Gain with load or gain without load?

Tags: voltage, resistance, feedback, gain, load

There is a problem I have been dealing with for hours.

In my Electronic 1 lecture, small signal analysis was like this:

[image]

The small signal equivalent of this circuit in my lecture notes was this:

[image]

When they calculate the no load voltage gain Av they do not remove the Rc. To me, Rc is the load but they do not accept.

[image]

In this semester in Electronic 2 lecture, the topic is feedback of amplifier circuit and this time they accept Rc is load (effective load this time) and when they calculate the no load open-loop gain they remove the Rc.

Why? Which one is correct?

[image]

(I am sorry for my bad  english)

Comment: The 1st included the Rce leakage which tends to be high R, Early effect) using 1/hOE , the 2nd ignores it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> according to me Rc is load

R<sub>c</sub> is not normally considered part of the load, but part of the amplifier circuit itself. The load is whatever is connected on the other side of the output coupling capacitor C<sub>2</sub>.

It's possible to design a common emitter amplifier where R<sub>c</sub> is absent and the load provides the collector bias current, but that isn't what was done here.